# PyTorch 2.0.0 DataLoader doesn't accept generators located on non-cpu devices

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

Reverse error to this [bug](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-expected-a-cuda-device-type-for-generator-but-found-cpu/161463), I have the tensors loaded on my gpu and I want the generator on the gpu for a DataLoader. Any advice on how to achieve this?

torch 2.0.0
python 3.10/3.11

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
device= torch.device("cuda")  # or torch.device("mps")
x, y - torch.tensor([1,2,3], device=device), torch.tensor([1,2,3], device=device)

gen = torch.Generator(device=device)
iter(DataLoader(TensorDataset(x, y), generator=torch.Generator(device='cuda')))
```